# Selecting random value from database and linking it to another row

Tags: php, mysql, select, random

I'm trying to link 2 rows in a database so that the PHP code will be selecting randomly a value from one row, and be linking it to the second row. example:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tel_Aviv");

$mysqli = new mysqli;
$mysqli->connect("localhost", "root", "", "root");

$giftsq = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `gifts`");
while($gifts = $giftsq->fetch_array())
{
    $date = date('H:i');
    if ($gifts['time'] <= $date)
    {
        $giftsid = $gifts['id'];
        // $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `gifts` WHERE `id` = '".$giftsid."'");
        $winner = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `giveaways` WHERE `giftid` = '".$giftsid."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1") or die('Error:'.$mysqli->error);
        if($winner->num_rows >= 1)
        {
            $newwinner = $winner->fetch_array;
            echo $newwinner['userid'];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

You can see that it selecting all the gift IDs that their dates are less than the current date or equal to it.
When the correct giftIDs are selected, the system want to select randomly a winner by selecting the same giftid on the second row called `giveaways`.

But for some reason its not working..

Here is the abstraction of the database:

### gifts

the time is is representing the end time of the gift giveaway.

```
id ------ title ------ img ------ creator ------ members ------ points ------ time
3         dota         1.png      Captain        250            30000         14:00
6         gta          2.png      User           303            20000         24:00
7         flolo        3.png      Captain        204            10000         22:30
```

### giveaways

```
id ------ giftid ------ userid
1           2           765611980448343721
2           6           765611980448343723
3           6           176561198044834371
4           6           176561198044834372
5           7           184582450892423483
6           7           423894024830294820
```

the result of all of this process is that I should be printing to the screen that the user id that has been selected for the giftid number 6 is randomly one of the following users:
176561198044834371
176561198044834372
176561198044834373

and the selected giftid number 7 is randomly one of the following users:
184582450892423483
423894024830294820

Can someone help me understanding how to do that?

Comment: So, you want to select all of the gifts that are equal to the current time, or less, and then choose a random user to get that gift?

Comment: @Kacey Exactly like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing the filtering in PHP? It's highly inefficient. Why not simply do

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE time <= CURTIME()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as much as possible with an SQL statement. There's probably a way you can combine them into one, but here's just a quick example:

```
$time = date("H:i");

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT gift_id FROM gifts WHERE gift_time <= '$time'");

while($row = $sql->fetch_array())
{
    $gift = $row['g_id'];

    $g_sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM giveaways WHERE gift_id = '$gift' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $g_row = $g_sql->fetch_array();

    echo '<p>' . $g_row['user_id'] . '</p>';
}
```